# is it necessary to call pthread_join()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I create more than 100 threads from my main() so I just wanted to know that do I need to call `pthread_join()` before I exit my main().
Also, I do not need the data generated by these threads, basically, all the threads are doing some job independent from main() and other threads.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`pthread_join` does two things:

1. Wait for the thread to finish.
2. Clean up any resources associated with the thread.

If you exit the process without joining, then (2) will be done for you by the OS (although it won't do thread cancellation cleanup, just nuke the thread from orbit), and (1) will not. So whether you need to call `pthread_join` depends whether you need (1) to happen.

If you don't need the thread to run, then as everyone else is saying you may as well detach it. A detached thread cannot be joined (so you can't wait on its completion), but its resources are freed automatically if it does complete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. so if i understand correctly .. all my threads would be killed if main threads exits .. so to avoid it i either have to call pthread_join() or pthread_detach() ... for my scenario as i do not need main() to keep waiting for all threads to complete i will simply call pthread_detach() and exit my main() and finally OS will safely free all resources used by all the threads on their completion ??

Comment: @user1271244: no. If you detach the threads they will be killed when the process exits, which is why I said "if you don't need the thread to run, you may as well detach it". If you need it to run, you must join it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if the thread is attachable then `pthread_join` is a must, otherwise it creates a Zombie thread.

I agree with the answers above, just sharing a note from man page of `pthread_join`.

NOTES:

```
   After a successful call to pthread_join(), the caller is guaranteed that the target thread has terminated.

   Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in undefined behavior.

   Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since each zombie thread consumes some  system  resources,  and  when
   enough zombie threads have accumulated, it will no longer be possible to create new threads (or processes).
```

Answer (score 3):

When you exit, you do not need to join because all other threads and resources will be automatically cleaned up.  This assumes that you actually want all the threads to be killed when `main` exits.

If you don't need to join with a thread, you can create it as a "detached" thread by using `pthread_attr_setdetachstate` on the attributes before creating the thread.  Detached threads cannot be joined, but they don't *need* to be joined either.

So,

1. If you want all threads to complete before the program finishes, joining from the main thread makes this work.
2. As an alternative, you can create the threads as detached, and return from `main` after all threads exit, coordinating using a semaphore or mutex+condition variable.
3. If you don't need all threads to complete, simply return from main.  All other threads will be destroyed.  You may also create the threads as detached threads, which may reduce resource consumption.

Comment: Note that in case (2), your co-ordination can ensure that you don't exit until the threads have done whatever it is they do before they post the semaphore or condvar. This should be good enough for all practical purposes, but it doesn't actually ensure that you don't exit until the threads have exited, since they exit at some unspecified time after they execute the code that notifies your main thread that something interesting has happened.

Answer (score 2):

By default threads in pthreads library are created as joinable.

Threads may, however, detach, rendering them no longer joinable. Because threads consume system resources until joined, just as processes consume resources until their parent calls wait(), threads that you do not intend to join must be detached, which is a good programming practice.

Of course once the main routine exits, all threading resources are freed.

If we fail to do that(detaching), then, when the thread terminates it produces the thread equivalent of a zombie process. Aside from wasting system resources, if enough thread zombies accumulate, we won't be able to create  additional threads.

Answer (score 1):

Per default a thread runs attached, that means the resources it needs are kept in use until the thread is joined.

As from your description noone but the thread itself needs the thread's resources, so you might create the thread detached or detach the thread prior to having it started.

To detach a thread after its creation call `pthread_detach()`.

Anyhow if you want to make sure all threads are gone before the program ends, you should run the threads attached and join them before leaving the main thread (the program).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that your thread have actually finished, you want to call `pthread_join`.

If you don't, then terminating your program will terminate all the unfinished thread abruptly.

That said, your `main` can wait a sufficiently long time until it exits. But then, how can you be sure that it is suffucient?

Answer (score -1):

If your main ends your application ends and your threads die... So you do need to use thread join (or use fork instead).