# join() threads without holding the main thread in python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a code that calls to threads over a loop, something like this:

```
def SubmitData(data):
    # creating the relevant command to execute
    command = CreateCommand(data)
    subprocess.call(command)

def Main():
    while(True):
        # generating some data
        data = GetData()
        MyThread = threading.Thread(target=SubmitData,args=(data,)) 
        MyThread.start()
```

obviously, I don't use `join()` on the **threads**.
My question is how to `join()` those **threads** without making the main thread wait for them?
Do I even need to `join()` them? what will happend if I won't `join()` them?

some important points:

- the *while* loop is suppose to for a very long time (couple of days)
- the *command* itself is not very long (few seconds)

I'm using threading for Performance so if someone have a better idea instead, I would like to try it out.

Comment: Possible answers to your question can be found at the following URL (it's not Python-specific, but the concepts are the same):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600250/is-it-necessary-to-call-pthread-join

Answer (score 1):

`Popen()` doesn't block. Unless `CreateCommand()` blocks, you could call `SubmitData()` in the main thread:

```
from subprocess import Popen

processes = []
while True:
    processes = [p for p in processes if p.poll() is None] # leave only running
    processes.append(Popen(CreateCommand(GetData()))) # start a new one
```

---

> Do I even need to join() them? what will happend if I won't join() them?

No. You don't need to join them. All non-daemonic threads are joined automatically when the main thread exits.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that the main thread supposed to run without exiting. creating a lot of threads without join them won't crush my program?

Comment: 1. don't use threads to run Popen 2. You don't need to join threads. Test it.

Comment: without threads the performance are very bad, (50 times slower), do you have a better idea to improve performance?

Comment: 50 times is significant and unbelievable if all you do is calling `Popen()`. Could you [provide a benchmark with dummy `data`, `command` that shows the result](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?