# Clean up a thread without .join() and without blocking the main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I am in a situation where I have two endpoints I can ask for a value, and one may be faster than the other. The calls to the endpoints are blocking. I want to wait for one to complete and take that result without waiting for the other to complete.

My solution was to issue the requests in separate threads and have those threads set a flag to true when they complete. In the main thread, I continuously check the flags (I know it is a busy wait, but that is not my primary concern right now) and when one completes it takes that value and returns it as the result.

The issue I have is that I never clean up the other thread. I can't find any way to do it without using `.join()`, which would just block and defeat the purpose of this whole thing. So, how can I clean up that other, slower thread that is blocking without joining it from the main thread?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean up the other thread", and why do you want to do that instead of just letting it run to completion? The work that would normally be called "clean up" should be performed by the "other thread" itself.

Comment: @MattTimmermans It is my understanding that if I do not call .join() on the thread, then even if it has finished its execution it will not actually be 'finished'. I know this is the case in C, but I don't have as much experience with python so maybe it is different here.

Comment: In Python threads terminate when their `run` method is completed: *Once the thread’s activity is started, the thread is considered ‘alive’. It stops being alive when its run() method terminates – either normally, or by raising an unhandled exception. The is_alive() method tests whether the thread is alive.*

Comment: You don't have to call `join` in python.  But maybe you *do* need to enforce some kind of limit on the number of these "zombie calls" you allow to run simultaneously.

Comment: Re, "I know this is the case in C."  I don't know about C, but in the C++ standard library, you'll get an error if you allow a `std::thread` object to be destroyed before you call either `t.join()` or `t.detach()`. That's purely a safety feature: They want to make sure you don't _accidentally_ leave the thread running after the `std::thread` handle is destroyed.  The `t.join()` call does what Python `join()` does.  The `t.detach()` call doesn't do anything but set a flag that means, "trust me, I know what I'm doing."

Comment: @SolomonSlow see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600250/is-it-necessary-to-call-pthread-join, basically in C `join` frees up any resources the thread was using (head space, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to make your threads `daemon`s, so when you get the result and finish your main, the other running thread will be forced to finish. You do that by changing the `daemon` keyword to `True`:

```py
tr = threading.Thread(daemon=True)
```

From the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) docs:

> The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits
>   when only daemon threads are left.

Although:

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such
>   as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
>   properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them
>   non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event).

I don't have any particular experience with `Event`s so can't elaborate on that. Feel free to click the link and read on.

Comment: I think that should work. I am going to repeat this process many times with the same two endpoints however, I am hoping that having a still active daemon thread from the previous call won't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

One bad and dirty solution is to implement a methode for the threads which close the socket which is blocking. Now you have to catch the exception in the main thread.

Comment: Ideally I do not want the main thread to have to do any cleanup. Aside from that, would this actually close the thread or would it still exist in an error state?

Comment: This kill the thread by a exception. If you dont catch this in the main thread this is killed,too.