# Unexpected behavior of Threading.join() - Code between calls to Threading.join()

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

Does the order of the Threading.join()s in **the source code** GUARANTEE the order of execution of the threads OR IS **IT SIMPLY to ensure that the main thread finishes UNTIL ALL THREADS FINISH**?

```
import threading, time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, duerme):
        super(myThread, self).__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.duerme = duerme

    def run(self):
        print("run()", self.name)
        time.sleep(self.duerme)
        print("%s termino " % self.name)


thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 20)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 12)
thread3 = myThread(3, "Thread-3", 6)

thread2.start()
thread1.start()
thread3.start()

thread3.join()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print("termino el hilo principal")
```

output:

```
run() Thread-2
run() Thread-1
run() Thread-3
Thread-3 termino
Thread-2 termino
Thread-1 termino
termino el hilo principal
```

If so, Can I see it as **a "hook"** (telling me that the code below the join()s is sure to be executed AFTER THREADS END ) that **simply tells me when threads end**?

If I put code between join()s (I change the last part):

```
thread3.join()
print("debajo del thread3")
thread1.join()
print("debajo del thread1")
thread2.join()
print("debajo del thread2")

print("termino el hilo principal")
```

I get this:

```
run() Thread-2
run() Thread-1
run() Thread-3
Thread-3 termino
debajo del thread3
Thread-2 termino
Thread-1 termino
debajo del thread1
debajo del thread2
termino el hilo principal
```

it is as if the phrase "debajo del thread2" **WAS waiting for thread1**.

Expected output:

```
run() Thread-2
run() Thread-1
run() Thread-3
Thread-3 termino
debajo del thread3
Thread-2 termino
debajo del thread2
Thread-1 termino
debajo del thread1
termino el hilo principal
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. join() simply means "pause until the thread finishes", nothing more.

Comment: In a word...YES.  You are pretty much right in everything you say.  `thread3.join()` quite literally just waits until `thread3` exits before moving on.  So long as you don't put any code between your calls to `join()`, it doesn't make any difference what order they are in....you are simply waiting for them all to end before you move on.  Once they all do end, anything you put after them will run.  But they aren't a `hook` and they don't `tell you` anything.  They just wait, much like a call to `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: the `threadx.join()`  delays the main thread until `threadx` finishes.

Comment: ok @CryptoFool, if I put something like this at the end:
thread3.join()
print("bottom of thread 3")
thread1.join()
print("below thread 1")
thread2.join()
print("bottom of thread 2")
print("end of the main thread") How it will be print?

Comment: "So long as you don't put any code between your calls to join()" I say it because of this sentence you told me

Comment: hi @freakishg great, what would happen if I put code between the join()s calls?

Comment: @IsaacDzikum, More accurate to say, join delays the _caller_ until the thread finishes. Any thread can `join()` any other thread. A simpler way to say the same thing: `threadx.join()` _does not return_ until `threadx` has finished.

Comment: Hi, @Solomon Slow what would happen if I put code between the join()s calls?, See the question, I updated

Comment: Your code will wait until thread3 finishes, then print a message, then wait until thread1 finishes, then print a message, then wait until thread2 finishes, then print two messages.

Comment: hi @David Schwartz No, I get this:
run() Thread-2
run() Thread-1
run() Thread-3
Thread-3 terminates 
below thread3
Thread-2 end 
Thread-1 end 
below thread1
below thread2
end main thread     :(

Comment: Re, "Slow what would happen if I put code between the join() calls?" Same as what would happen if you put code between any other calls (or, between any other two statements for that matter.) First it would do the one `join()` call, and then it would do the "between" stuff, and then it would do the next `join()` call.

Comment: "Does the order of the Threading.join()s in the source code GUARANTEE the order of execution of the threads" - if you look at your `print` output, you will see that the execution order of the threads already doesn't match the order of the `join`s.

Comment: Thanks @David Schwartz I set a time of 80 to thread1 and 100 to thread2 and I could notice what you told me. The messages "print("below thread1")" and "print("below thread2")" were going out together (one right after the other) because when thread1 ended, thread2 had already ended "THAT'S WHY THE EFFECT WAS NOT CLEAR".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the order of the Threading.join()s in the source code GUARANTEE the order of execution of the threads

Which threads are you asking about? If you are asking about order of execution of `thread1`, `thread2`, and `thread3`, then then answer is, absolutely NOT.  When you call `t.join()` it does not do anything at all to thread `t`. IMO, the best way to think of `join` is, it does *nothing,* and it keeps doing nothing until thread `t` has finished, and then it returns.

OTOH, if you are asking about your *main* thread, then yes, when your main thread calls `threadN.join()`, then your main thread will be "blocked" until `threadN` is finished.

> ...order of execution of the threads...

Your `thread1`, `thread2`, and `thread3` are completely unsynchronized. They run [*concurrently*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)).* "Concurrency" means there are no guarantees about which thread does what, when unless they do something that explicitly synchronizes them.

An example of explicit synchronization would be if one thread releases a mutex that some other thread is waiting for. The thread that is waiting for the mutex is guaranteed not to proceed until the first thread releases it.

Another example of something that synchronizes threads is `join`. When thread A joins thread B, then thread A is guaranteed not to proceed until after thread B has ended.

---

* Doing things concurrently is the entire point of using threads. If you don't want concurrency, then don't use threads.

Comment: Ok @Solomon Slow then join(), it can ALSO be seen as a "Thread.sleep()" as the guys say in the comments.

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer. Yes. Like the guy said, they are similar. `Thread.sleep(n)` does _nothing._ It does _nothing_ for `n` seconds, and then it returns.

Comment: "Another example of something that synchronizes threads is join. When thread A joins thread B, then thread A is guaranteed not to proceed until after thread B has ended" - great @Solomon Slow this worth gold +1

Comment: Thanks @Slow Solomon NOW I JUST DON'T 100% UNDERSTAND my output when I put code between join()s :(

Comment: it's as if the phrase "por debajo del thread2" WAS waiting for thread1, when it shouldn't as it should only wait for thread2  or what do you think @Solomon Slow?

Comment: The three `print("debajo del...")` statements all happen in the same thread (the main thread.) They must happen in _program order_ (i.e., in the same order in which they appear in the source code.) Meanwhile, the `print("%s termino"...)` statement is executed by three _different_ threads. Because they happen _concurrently,_ those three `print` calls could happen in _any_ order. Just because your main program waits for `thread3` before waiting for the other two does _not_ mean that thread3 will finish before the other two finish. They could finish in any order.

Comment: great @solomon slow, the 3 print("below the...") come out in random order (which is NORMAL because it's the nature of concurrency and it shouldn't matter the order) and the TRULY IMPORTANT thing in this case is that THEY WERE PRINTED AFTER THE 3 threads ENDED, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer, Re, "the 3 print("below the...") come out in random order..." Really? Based on your code examples and the actual output that you showed, it looks to me as if those three `print` statements always come out in exactly the same order as they appear in your source code. And, that is what I would expect because that code is executed by a single thread.

Comment: Thanks, @Solomon Slow, to conclude, so the "program order" (the instructions as they are in the source code of the thread in question) of ANY thread is FULLY GUARANTEED? - Done, marked as best answer

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your questions:

> Does the order of the Threading.join()s in the source code GUARANTEE
> the order of execution of the threads

The answer is **No**. The order of execution can be somewhat handled by using locks (mutexes, semaphores, ...). They allow you to sychronize certain pieces of your code, so that only one thread have exclusive access to an atomic expression or shared data at a time. But the order is always random, and that's ok because that's how threads should work.

In a parallel environment, you don't really know if *thread A* executes or finishes first or after *thread B*.

If you want to *ensure* that they are in synchrony (A executes first, B executes after A), don't use threads. Use their instructions on the main thread one after another.

---

> OR IS IT SIMPLY to ensure that the main thread finishes UNTIL ALL
> THREADS FINISH?

**Not necessarily**. If you don't want to wait for a thread to be finished, that's ok. Python or the OS should handle it's destruction in a proper way (unless an error occurs, which can happen).

`Thread.join()` should be called if you need to wait (block the current thread) for that single thread to be finished.

In my opinion, it's good practice to join a thread at the end of each script, so you know you are releasing resources once the application finishes executing. But, on many answers found on the internet, [even on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600250/is-it-necessary-to-call-pthread-join), its stated that it depends on what you want to do. If the thread needs to run even after the application finishes executing, it's resources will be released after the thread finishes its operation.

---

> If so, Can I see it as a "hook" (telling me that the code below the
> join()s is sure to be executed AFTER THREADS END ) that simply tells
> me when threads end?

Again. It doesn't tell wether a thread has ended. It blocks the current thread until the targeted thread finishes executing (`Thread.run()` goes out of scope).

It's a blocking function that returns `None` as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join). If you need to know wether the thread is still running, use `Thread.is_alive()`.

---

Now about your **EDIT**:

> If I put code between join()s (I change the last part):
>
> ```
> thread3.join()
> print("debajo del thread3")
> thread1.join()
> print("debajo del thread1")
> thread2.join()
> print("debajo del thread2")
>
> print("termino el hilo principal")
> ```
>
> I get this:
>
> ```
> run() Thread-2
> run() Thread-1
> run() Thread-3
> Thread-3 termino
> debajo del thread3
> Thread-2 termino
> Thread-1 termino
> debajo del thread1
> debajo del thread2
> termino el hilo principal
> ```

This is how your threads work:

1. When they start, they print the `run` string.
2. They wait for a pre-determinated amount of seconds.

   - *Thread 1* waits for *20 seconds*
   - *Thread 2* waits for *12 seconds*
   - *Thread 3* waits for *6 seconds*
3. When they finish waiting, they print the `termino` string.

So, let's run the script! All threads start right now. The starting order of each thread is mostly random. *Thread 2* can start first, or maybe *Thread 1* can be the last. The order depends on how the OS / Python interpreter schedules the threads execution.

Regardless of which started first, all of them become stuck once they reach the `time.sleep()` function, waiting for their own timeout.

During this waiting, at the same time, the main thread joins *Thread 3*. It blocks itself (while other threads are still sleeping), and waits for *Thread 3* to awake and go out of scope.

After 6 seconds or more, that happens. Thread 3 goes out of scope, printing the `Thread-3 termino` string.

Now, main thread becomes responsive again, and goes for its next instruction while *Thread 1* and *Thread 2* are still sleeping. It joins *Thread 1*, freezing itself until *Thread 1* goes out of scope.

12 seconds pass, and *Thread 2* goes out of scope, printing the `Thread-2 termino` string. 20 seconds pass, and *Thread 1* goes out of scope, printing the `Thread-1 termino` as well. Then, main thread becomes responsive again, and goes for its next instruction: join *Thread 2*.

It freezes itself waiting for *Thread 2* to go out of scope. However this thread is already finished. So the waiting is instant, and the main thread moves to its next instructions until the script finishes executing.

That's what should happen based on the script you wrote. `Thread.join()` does not control which thread finishes executing first. It controls wether the main thread may procede after a thread has gone out of scope on their `Thread.run()` method. While `Thread.join()` has been called, and the *current thread* is put to sleep, all the other threads will keep executing normally because they are running in parallel. They may even go out of scope before the *joined thread* awakes the *current thread*.

Comment: "They allow you to sychronize certain pieces of your code, so that only one thread have exclusive access to an atomic expression or shared data at a time. But the order is always random, and that's ok because that's how threads should work.- "Awesome @Carl HR so locks (of any kind) ONLY HELP make certain code ATOMIC (like database transactions) BUT STILL STILL a parallel environment (we shouldn't care about order) ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you need to edit a shared resource (with am atomic expression or a very complex one), you may use a mutex to lock access to the memory only to the current thread. If you need make *Thread A* print something before *Thread B*, you could use your own mutex logic to ensure it is done in that order. It's not that you shouldn't care about order of events, but when using multithreading, this kind of thing should be just minimized, not non-existent.

Comment: The reason IMO is because its very difficult to create order in chaos (parallel envrionment), and synchronization mostly decreases processing speed by making other threads wait while one is executing. Multithreading is ideal when each thread doesn't need to comunicate or wait for each other (i.e. they all execute independently of each other).

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer if you're still in doubt of what mutexes and semaphores are for, I suggest you to dig into it. There are many [tutorials and articles](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-vs-semaphore/) that show you what they are for. It's not a Python's concept, but a broad one used on many different scripting languages.

Comment: great @Carl HR so, do the 3 print("debajo del....") come out in random order (which is NORMAL due to concurrency) but the REAL IMPORTANT thing in this case, is that THEY ARE PRINTED AFTER THE 3 threads END due to the join(), right?, This is how I understood your execution narrative

Comment: Yes, the `debajo del...` prints appear only after the `Thread-x termino` prints because that the `Thread.join()` waits for the thread to go out of scope (and the `Thread-x termino` print will be executed *before* the thread reaches the end of scope). But the `debajo del...` prints should not be printed *out-of-order* because they are only called in the same thread (the *main thread*). So, `debajo del thread3` prints first, then `debajo del thread1` and lastly `debajo del thread2`.

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer `Thread.join()` could also be thought of being an implicit access to an *already-locked* mutex. It blocks the *current thread* until the the *other thread's* run method goes reaches the end of its scope during its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, now I understand the join(), for that I put a time of 80 to thread1 and 100 to thread2 and I could notice what you told me. The messages "print("below thread1")" and "print("below thread2")" were coming out together (**one right after the other**) because when thread1 ended, **thread2 had already ended** "**THAT'S WHY THE EFFECT OF "WAIT" WAS NOT CLEAR**".

**Definitely the Threading.join() can be seen as a kind of "Thread.sleep()" the current thread until the t.join() finishes.**

Sorry everyone, I'm new to threads but this IS THE HARDEST thing to understand in this world. Now the hard part is to choose the best answer hehe.

So I leave the code in case you want to understand the "wait" of join():

```
import threading, time


class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, duerme):
        super(myThread, self).__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.duerme = duerme

    def run(self):
        print("run()", self.name)
        time.sleep(self.duerme)
        print("%s termino " % self.name)


thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 80)
#I had to increase the wait of thread 2 so that the wait of the current 
#thread is appreciated (and the "interleaved" messages that SHOW THE 
#WAIT are visible).
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 100)

thread3 = myThread(3, "Thread-3", 6)

thread2.start()
thread1.start()
thread3.start()

thread3.join()
print("debajo del thread3")
print("antes de thread1.join()")
thread1.join()
print("debajo del thread1")
thread2.join()
print("debajo del thread2")

print("termino el hilo principal")
```

Output:

```
run() Thread-2
run() Thread-1
run() Thread-3
Thread-3 termino
debajo del thread3
antes de thread1.join()
Thread-1 termino 
debajo del thread1 //This was the hard to see effect
Thread-2 termino 
debajo del thread2
termino el hilo principal
```

Comment: It's hard to understand because you never needed to use it. Swallowing it all at first is hard, sure, but if you start programming with GUI, networking or machine learning for example, parallel processing and multithreading become more of an obvious concept to try on your next script. You get used to it with time and practice.